# Laravel return empty when eager child relationship is empty

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to fetch the data from table name `pos_receipt`. It has a child table which contains a column `receipt_id` of `pos_receipt` primary key. I just want to return empty if child table has no relationship with parent table. Right now its returning the data with empty array of parent if there is no relationship. It should return empty array if there is no relationship in child table

Here is the query :

```
 $options = PosReceipt::with([
                    'transferBranch' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('branch_id',2);
                    },
                ])
                ->where('receipt_no','LIKE','%'.$filters->keyword.'%')
                ->whereDate('receipt_date','>=', $date1)
                ->whereDate('receipt_date','<=', $date2)
                ->where('type', 'TRN')
                ->limit(20)
                ->offset($request->start)
                ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                ->get();
```

AND THE RELATIONSHIP FOR THE MODEL FOR transferBranch relation is
//MODEL CALSS OF PosReceipt

```
public function transferBranch()
{   
    return $this->hasMany(TransferStore::class,'receipt_id');
}
```

Comment: Add your migration code and the model code for both tables.

Answer (score 1):

incase if someone needs a solution

```
$options = PosReceipt::with([
                'transferBranch'
            ])
            ->whereHas("transferBranch",function($q) use($filters){
                $q->where("branch_id","=",$filters->storeID);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The hasMany method has 3 arguments.

```
/**
 * Define a one-to-many relationship.
 *
 * @param  string  $related
 * @param  string|null  $foreignKey
 * @param  string|null  $localKey
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
```

Try changing to

```
 return $this->hasMany(TransferStore::class,'receipt_id','id');
```

And make sure youre using this at the top of the model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
```

Comment: It still returning the parent data with empty child array . I just wanted if child is empty it should not return the parents data just wanted LIKE INNER JOIN query with store_transfer table using eager.